# Combining Bootstrap and Validator

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

So I'm rebuilding my registration page with bootstrap. And I am trying to incorporate jquery's validator plugin to validate the form. The first thing I did is I split the form up into three parts, each part with its own tab. The first page of the form contains 3 radio button options, which the use has to select one of before moving onto the next page/tab/part. So here's my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#options" data-toggle="tab">Options</a></li>
  <li><a href="#information" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
  <li><a href="#payment" data-toggle="tab">Payment</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="options">
    <form id="frmtype1" action="" name="frmtype1" method="post">
        <header>Registration Options</header>
        <br/>
        <label for="Reg_type1" class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type1" value="1" validate="required:true"/>
        Registering myself with credit card or bank account
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="Reg_type2" class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type2" value="2"/>
        Registering multiple people using credit card or bank account
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="Reg_type3" class="checkbox">
            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type3" value="3"/>
        Registering using a purchase order
        </label>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <span class="help-inline" style="display:none;">Please choose an option</span><button class="btn" type="submit">Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>             
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="information">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="payment">...</div>
</div>
```

Then my jquery is:

```
var val1 = $('#frmtype1').validate();
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

What I want to do is, if the user tries to click next before selecting an option, i want to display the inline text saying `Please choose an option` otherwise move onto the next tab. How exactly do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply place this jquery to validate the radio buttons:

```
var val1 = $('#frmtype1').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}, //this is to prevent the standard error message from showing, rather you use the inline-text
    rules: {
        'Reg_type': {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

And then this to show/hide the error message:

```
$('#frmtype1').submit(function(e) {
    if(val1.form()) {
        $('.help-inline').hide();
    } else {
        $('.help-inline').show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the form in the active tab and check if it is valid. If it isn't, display your message and stop the event.

```
$(".nav-tabs a").click(function(e) {
    var form = $( ".tab-pane.active" );
    if ( !form.valid() ) {
        alert("You must complete the form before continuing to the next tab.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to display the inline text rather than the alert.

Comment: It should already be doing that after calling `.valid()` if you previously called `.validate()` on the form. (`.validate()` doesn't belong inside this click event, FYI)